# Convert DataType of last row in Datatable for export to Excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, datatable

Is there any way to turn Datatype of the only last row  When I want to export excel from Datatable?

```
 dataTable.Columns("ColumnA").DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
```

It seems that Datatype just only can be used by Columns....?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You only can for columns...

Comment: You mean you want the data of the last row to be a string before you Export it into Excel? Can you just change the `NumberFormat` of the cell to `"@"`?

Comment: @CrushSundae yes! I am the beginner of VB. Can you give some specific code?Thank you!!

Comment: I cannot help you that much, can you also post your code on how you are exporting to Excel?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is - NO. You can't change datatype just like that. What you can do is - add a column of desired data type and insert converted data into that column.

We don't know HOW you export to excel. It shouldn't be that hard if you already have `DataTable`. All you need is use `Microsoft.ACE.OleDb` and feed your data table into excel.

I suspect you might have some loop and you can do this

```
Dim iterations As Integer = table.Rows.Count - 1
For i As Integer = 0 To iterations

   If i = iterations AndAlso table.Rows(i)("ColumnA") <> DbNull.Value Then
       ' Convert table.Rows(i)("ColumnA") to the desired type
       Return
   End If
   ' here process all rows but last
   . . . . . . . . 

Next
```